# I have doubts on shirk

Tags: allah, shirk, forgiveness, doubts

Sometimes when I see a black cat and I would worry and get thoughts is this believing in shirk please help I do not want to commit shirk I just get these worries I’m guessing I’m just worried if these worries lead to shirk as they are doubts not certain i believe in Allah as the only god and prophet Muhammad is the messenger but I get worried if this leads to shirk

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, Allah will help you and he won't let you get in  shirk, if you want to stay away from shirk allah will help you, he will not leave you alone ,Allah says in Quran (and those who strive for us, we will surely guide them to our ways, and indeed allah is with the doers of good)(29:69)

Answer (score 0):

Brother,you are suffering from waswas
Shaitaan is playing with you
Ignore the thoughts thats the only solution
And please pray for me as i am suffering from a similar sittuation like you